# How do i fix this code so that it wont pop_back or back() if the vector/stack is empty?

Tags: c++, class, stack

There is something wrong with my Stack.h and I'm unsure what I am missing. I am receiving a segmentation fault error. I know it has to do with the "void pop()" and "T top()" functions. I'm pretty sure this is caused by an empty stack. By only editing these two functions, how can I ensure that my program will run? My .cpp file needs to have the s2.pop outside of the (!s2.empty) check.

Comment: Sounds like an X Y problem to me. "My .cpp file needs to have the s2.pop outside of the (!s2.empty) check." **WHY?** This doesn't make sense since you empty the stack in the previous loop. You'd always execute it on an empty one.

Comment: If you don't want the question anymore then delete it. But don't just edit it, others reaching this through search or other means would just get unnecessarily confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you should really remove the `s2.pop()` at the end. It doesn't make sense with it there.

```
while (!s2.empty()) {
    cout << s2.top();
    s2.pop();
} // s2 is always empty by now, another pop() wouldn't make sense.
cout << endl;
s2.pop();
```

You could change your `pop()` function to

```
void pop() {
    if (!empty())
        container.pop_back();
}
```

Then your `pop()` would work even on an empty Stack, but your `top()` would still crash. You can't fix `top()` that easy either, so that you'd end up with different behaviours which is confusing and you shouldn't have. Or some unintuitive implementations which are also bad.

Comment: Right. I did actually figure out the if statement for the pop function, however I can't do top() that easily. There IS a way though.

Comment: @user3579810 Yes, instead of undefined behaviour (possibly as segmentation fault) you could throw an exception when it's empty and have the caller handle exceptions. (Checking if it's empty before actually calling `top` is way easier than this.) You could also return a `pair<bool, T>` with the `bool` indicating if it actually worked or the `T` is just some default constructed dummy value. Or return a bool and take the T as reference argument. All of them are ugly. You're trying to make it difficult for no real reason.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the very last line, `s2.pop();`. By the time you get there, the stack is already empty, since the stack's being empty was the exit condition for the loop just above.

Comment: My issue is within the header file since s2.pop(); must remain. I'm trying to figure out how to avoid a segmentation fault under this condition.

Comment: @user3579810 you don't need to. it's caller's responsibility to check if a stack is empty or not before calling pop.

Comment: I could make it run by removing the last line and it would work, however I'd like to figure out a simple way to edit my functions in the header file to bypass this issue and have it print regardless. Is there no way? Understand this is for the sake of progressing my knowledge.

Comment: @user3579810 your question either doesn't make sense in its current form or you're trying to do something you really shouldn't.

Comment: @user3579810: You could make `pop` a no-op if the container is already empty.